# Get value of TextBox in Word by but in Word template

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-template

Background: I want to use a specific entered text from a TextBox for the default filename in the SaveAs dialog.

I have implemented the following VBA script in my document, a Word 2010 template .dotm

```
Sub FileSaveAs()

'for testing
Dim fileName As String
fileName = Me.tb_myTextBox.Value & "_MyFileNameToSave"
MsgBox fileName

'use specific file name in save dialog
With Dialogs(wdDialogFileSaveAs)
  .Name = fileName
  .Show
 End With

End Sub
```

It works fine, when I run it. I saved the .dotm, closed it and reopened it out from the Windows Explorer (means as "end user").
BUT in this case, means after open the template document as "end user" (so that I can save a new doc out of it and not overwrite the template), the content/value of the TextBox is empty, even if I entered something into it.

So, how can I read out the data of the TextBox in "document mode" of a template?

Comment: You should edit your question to share your exact steps, I don't understand what is not working for you. Also, your code is incomplete and anyone who offers help will need to fill in the blanks, which could lead to confusion.

Comment: Ok, new try of explanation... there are two cases:
- (1) editing the template, if you save it, it is again .dotm. In this case all works fine with the script.
- (2) open the template as "end user" (and not as template-author). If the user clicks the Save-button, the document is saved as .doc and not .dotm. In this case, the script does NOT work!

btw: where the code is incomplete?? *confused*

Comment: @SiddharthRout: The TextBox is just located on the page (root level).
The VBA script is saved in "This document" source code (and not in a module).

Comment: Did you solve this? If not, I can steer you in the right direction...

Comment: Textbox is in a userform or is it a graphical textbox in a document? If your document is a genuine Word template and not simply a format to be followed or a sample document, then when it is used it is not opened. Instead a new, unnamed, document is created.

Answer (score 2):

Presumably, the OP's intention was something along the lines of:

```
Sub FileSaveAs()
Dim StrNm As String
With ActiveDocument
  StrNm = Split(.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text, vbCr)(0) & "_MyFileNameToSave"
  'use specific file name in save dialog
  With Dialogs(wdDialogFileSaveAs)
    .Name = StrNm
    .Show
  End With
End With
End Sub
```

where .Shapes(1) identifies the particular textbox Shape object.

Answer (score 0):

> how can I read out the data of the TextBox in "document mode" of a template?

Not sure what you mean. This works for me:

create a form:

```
Private Sub btn_OK_Click()
    Dim fileName As String
    fileName = tb_myTextBox.Value & "_MyFileNameToSave"
    With Dialogs(wdDialogFileSaveAs)
      .name = fileName
      .Show
     End With
End Sub
```

create a sub to call this form:

```
 Sub FileSaveAs()
    UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```

This is all saved in a template / .dotm.

Now, create a document off of the template (double click the template to launch document off of it). Alt + F8 and run the macro from the template (you may have to select the template from the "Macros in" drop down). Result: my form comes up, I enter a name for the document, press ok, and the Word Save As dialog appears with the name I gave to the document.

Comment: Thanks for reply! 
Problem is, that I do not have an additional Save button. The "FileSaveAs()" sub function shall be (automatically) called, after the user clicks on Save(As) button/menu entry.

Comment: So FileSaveAs is not intercepting the user doing a File | Save As? I don't understand the problem so I need o recreate it.

Comment: No, my Sub is called when the user clicks File | Save (as). So the call of the function works fine! But the TextField is located in the document and not in an extra user form. Also have a look to my comment in the question. It is very strange, why all works in case 1, but not in case 2. :-/