Error Popping up when saving read only file as save as
I need to have a read only Word macro File that makes the user save it first as what ever they choose the name to be as long as it doesn't override the read only file. It also doesn't matter if the file is saved as read only or not. This is button activated
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim objOutlook As Object
Dim objOutlookMsg As Object
Dim objInspector As Object
Dim objDoc As Word.Document
Dim objRange As Range
Dim sDocname As String
    ActiveDocument.Save
    sDocname = ActiveDocument.FullName
    If Len(ActiveDocument.Path) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Document is not saved!, Save and Try again"
        GoTo lbl_Exit
    End If
    On Error Resume Next

The code continues to send the email.
The error pops up

Run-Time error "5155" We can't save this file because it's read only.

It then debugs to ActiveDocument.Save
Weirdly enough it does save still but kills the code and pops up with the error.
I'm very much new and copy most of this code. But after reading for about 4 hours and doing a bunch of changes would very much appreciate guidance on this. thanks

You get the error because you are using ActiveDocument.Save instead of ActiveDocument.SaveAs see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.saveas2 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.readonly

I have tried this and it doesn't work. It heads straight to the debug error with the same error and highlights the same line. It doesn't give the option to save at all and doesn't save.

Have a look at this Q/A: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11363427/get-value-of-textbox-in-word-by-but-in-word-template
